# Linux virtual memory consumption after parsing log file

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

I wrote a parser to read the auth.log. For some reason while parsing `auth.log` I get that `VSZ` is larger than the total physical memory, which is `2GB`. Depending on the size of auth.log and how long reader has been running, `VSZ` will increase (sometimes up to ~8GB).

How normal is it? What could be the reason of this memory consumption?

```
# ps aux
USER   PID  CPU %MEM     VSZ   RSS   TTY STAT START  TIME  COMMAND
root 17547  0.7  1.4 3123744 30820 pts/2  Sl+ Jul30 11:42 ./reader auth.log

# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2063568    1842232     221336          0     179084    1057680
-/+ buffers/cache:     605468    1458100
Swap:      4032504        288    4032216
```

Comment: Without seeing the script, the most likely reason is you are reading the entire log into memory, or you have a memory leak through not releasing resources.  Would you like to add the script to the post?

Comment: @Paul: Is that were true, why would his resident set size be so low?

Comment: @Paul: Thanks. Yes, I'm reading almost the entire log into memory. I'm not able to post it due to my job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. Virtual memory is so cheap, effectively free, that there's pretty much no point in trying to reduce your consumption of it.

Comment: Thanks. Could this potentially crash the machine if it gets to large for one process?

Comment: @MikeDarrow: No. Virtual memory is just address space.